# Is the number 11 associated with Witchcraft or is this merely a superstition?

Tags: sihr

Recently, I saw a YouTube video where a Sheikh/Imam claims that the number 11 is associated with Witchcraft ( tying 11 knots or something ) , and all the multiples of it ( 11, 22, 33. ..) are also associated with Witchcraft. Is this true  ?

There are some Islamic contradictions to this;

1. We pray 11 rakat  ( with sun nah ) each night
2. We say Alhamdulillah and Subhanallah 33 times

These examples contradict the idea that 11 is associated wit witchcraft. Nevertheless,  can someone explain THIS  ?

Comment: wow we really have a long way to go.

Comment: @secret squirrel  What is that supposed to mean  ?

Comment: when you say "there are some Islamic contradictions to this", well witchcraft is kufr and disbelief, so it obviously contradicts everything about Islam. And secondly the number 11 is associated only with the number 11. If I pay 11 dirhams in zakat or go to the mosque 11 times in a week then that doesn't mean anything, and thirdly the number of sunnah rakats is not fixed; actually its optionally 8 sunnah rakats; also according to my calculator 11 is not 33.

Comment: I said that 33 is a multiple of 11. Don't you know what's a MULTIPLE  ? Ask your Math Teacher

Comment: At  night we pray 2 sunnah + 4fard  (isha) + 2 sunnah + 3 witr = 11 Rakat total

Answer (score 0):

So, if **witchcraft** is associated with something, what does that have to do with Islam ????

If I tell people to jump in a lake, what has that got to do with Islam ?

Islam is Allah's final revelation that was brought by Muhammad saw, the seal of the Prophets, who will lead his ummah on the day of resurrection. If someone wants to do x, y or z then its nothing to do with Islam unless it is based on the quran and sunna.

Comment: You completely misunderstand me

Comment: you can't make a connection between two things which aren't connected. For example, we believe Allah is one. At the same time, on the US ONE dollar bill there is ONE pyramid with ONE eye. Is there a connection ??? There is no connection. The source of Islam is quran and sunnah, the source of the bill is historic US economic law. If someone makes a connection, that connection is only in their mind; the two things are not connected.

Comment: The said YouTube video actually mentioned such a connection. I can't remember what was the conncectiln , and I can't find it out because I am unable to identify which video was it.